# Crear boton para llamar a un número

Tags: android

Estoy intentando llamar a un número de teléfono específico desde un botón, pero no me sale, creo que esta todo correcto.

Esta es mi clase FragmentoDirecciones:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.herprogramacion.restaurantericoparico.R;


public class FragmentoDirecciones extends Fragment {

    private LinearLayoutManager linearLayout;

    public FragmentoDirecciones() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmento_grupo_items, container, false);

        RecyclerView reciclador = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.reciclador);
        linearLayout = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        reciclador.setLayoutManager(linearLayout);

        AdaptadorDirecciones adaptador = new AdaptadorDirecciones();
        reciclador.setAdapter(adaptador);
        reciclador.addItemDecoration(new DecoracionLineaDivisoria(getActivity()));

        return view;
    }

    public void onClickLlamada(View v) {

        Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_CALL,
                Uri.parse("tel:0000000"));
        startActivity(i);
    }

}
```

y este es mi item_lista_direccion.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/espacio_norma_1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/texto_direccion"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Dirección"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/texto_direccion_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Departamento"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/texto_telefono"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Ciudad"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/texto_cerrado"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Teléfono"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/icono_indicador_derecho"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/call"
        android:onClick="onClickLlamada"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

En el Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
```

fragmento_grupo_items.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/reciclador"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

Por que no me funciona?

Comment: Rafa veo que tienes permiso e incluso llamas correctamente desde el boton correctamente el metodo onClickLlamada, realiza lo que pongo en mi respuesta y comenta que resultados tienes. Agrega un numero, no solo valores con 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veo que tienes configurado todo correctamente, incluso la llamada desde el layout al método, configura el telefono mediante el método [setData()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setData(android.net.Uri)) del Intent :

```
    public void onClickLlamada(View v) {
       Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
       i.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));
       startActivity(i);
    }
```

Asegura también que el permiso

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

este especificado al mismo nivel que el tag `<application` en tu `AndroidManifest.xml`

**Actualización:**
El fragment `FragmentoDirecciones` carga el layout `fragmento_grupo_items.xml`, se debe asegurar que dentro de este layout se encuentre en verdad el boton con la llamada al método `onClickLlamada`:

```
android:onClick="onClickLlamada"
```

Comment: Este es el error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method onClickLlamada(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'button'

Comment: Rafa el layout fragmento_grupo_items.xml es en verdad el que contiene el button??? Si no encuentra el método es porque el fragmento que no contiene el método, carga el layout con el android:onClick="onClickLlamada".

Comment: pues en el fragmento_grupo_items.xml no ponia el boton, vaya fallo el fragmento_grupo_items.xml, es un recycler que lo habre el class que pongo en el post 1. pero no se como hacerlo funcionar. Gracias.

Comment: hola el ajemplo me fue util pero tengo un problema cuando en pogo el sibolo de # no seme muestra el numero completo ejemplo public void onClickLlamada(View v) { Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL); i.setData(Uri.parse("tel:*222#")); startActivity(i); } esto es para cosultal el sado todo lo realise como ustedes nesecito una ayuda soy nuebo en programacion. espero su repuesta graci por el ejmplo

Comment: esto me llama directamente, como haria para que me habra la aplicacion contactos con el numero predefinido ?